# When working with DataFrames dropna() seems to not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def convert_categorical_sex(df2):
    frame = df2.dropna(subset=['Sex'])
    sex = frame.Sex.map( {'F': 1, 'M': 0} ).astype(int)
    print(sex.isna().sum())
    return sex
```

This prints 0 for the number of NaNs. When I add it to my dataframe

```
c_data['Sex'] = convert_categorical_sex(data)
c_data.Sex.isna().sum()
```

This prints 2. I am not changing anything and there is no reason more NaNs would appear. If I try to remove it with dropna() it doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: After dropna, you drop some row , and index is not match with original df, then when you do assign , it will show NaN for the index not exit row

Comment: You `dropna` on your DataFrame before applying the transformation.  Do you *not* `dropna` on your `c_data` before reassigning?

Comment: W-B you are right. That was the problem. I assigned the column to the DataFrame that had more rows so it reintroduced the removed NaNs. Thank you.